# Angular 2 application with no server?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

How to run Angular 2 application without running a server?
I need to take just one folder which contains index.html (some css, js additionally)

Comment: you can simply install angular package with node js , furthers reading here :https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use angular-cli you can do `ng build --prod`. The index.html will be in the dist folder.

Comment: I did like u said. But when i run index.html from dist folder i'm getting an empty page with the message "loading..." on top. Where can be the problem ?

Comment: You need to run `index.html` from a server, not just open the file in your browser. Check out the browser console, you're probably getting 404 errors for all the js/css files that `index.html` is trying to load.

Comment: So i cant run my Angular2 Application without running a server ?

Comment: @ArtemyWiese You can, do as al37350 said but to solve your error edit created index.html file and change <base href="/"> with <base href="./"> 

Also it is important that your router strategy is Location, not Hash.

Answer (score 0):

Completing Admir Sabanovic's answer. In your app.module.ts add as provider

```
providers: [
   { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
]
```

In your index.html change the line < base href="./" > by

```
<script>document.write("<base href='"+window.location.href+"'/>") </script>
```